# Matlab: How to output a matrix which is sorted by distance

Tags: matlab, matrix, point-clouds

I have a cluster of points in 3D point clouds, says

```
    A = [ 1 4 3;
    1 2 3;
    1 6 3;
    1 5 3];
```

The distance matrix then was found:

```
    D= pdist(A);
    Z= squareform(D);
    Z =

 0     2     2     1
 2     0     4     3
 2     4     0     1
 1     3     1     0
```

I would like to sort the points so that the sum of the distance travelled through the points will be the smallest, and output in another matrix. This is similar to TSP problem but in a 3D model. Is there any function can do this?
Your help is really appreciated in advance.

Comment: Please explain or elaborate on what "sum of the distance travelled through the points" means.  I'm having a hard time understanding your problem statement.  Can you please show us a numerical example on what this output matrix looks like, and what you would like done with this matrix?

Comment: Sounds like the Travelling Salesman problem, except somewhat simpler because costs are distances and respect the triangle bound.

Comment: @rayryeng : Sorry about the confusion. The meaning of " sum of the distance traveled through the points" means that if there is 4 points in my matrix, says (1,4,3) (1,2,3) (1,6,3) and (1,5,3), now I would like to find out how to travel all the 4 points once without repetition with shortest distance. And the output will be the sequence of the points in the shortest path.

Comment: @BenVoigt: thanks for the comment and yes, it is similar to TSP but I am just wondering how to output the sorted points into a matrix. You have any idea?

Comment: @ElayneEngTengSin - I understand now.  Thank you for the clarification.  I've written an answer.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be one approach and must be efficient enough for a wide range of datasizes -

```
D = pdist(A);
Z = squareform(D);  %// Get distance matrix

N = size(A,1);      %// Store the size of the input array for later usage
Z(1:N+1:end) = Inf; %// Set diagonals as Infinites as we intend to find
                    %// minimum along each row

%// Starting point and initialize an array to store the indices according
%// to the sorted requirements set in the question
idx = 1;
out_idx = zeros(N,1);
out_idx(1) = idx;

%// Perform an iterative search to look for nearest one starting from point-1
for k = 2:N
    start_ind = idx;
    [~,idx] = min(Z(start_ind,:));
    Z(:,start_ind) = Inf;
    out_idx(k) = idx;
end

%// Now that you have the list of indices based on the next closest one, 
%// sort the input array based on those indices and have the desired output 
out = A(out_idx,:)
```

Sample run for given input -

```
A =
     1     4     3
     1     2     3
     1     6     3
     1     5     3
     1     2     3
out =
     1     4     3
     1     5     3
     1     6     3
     1     2     3
     1     2     3
```

Comment: @ElayneEngTengSin Awesome! Just curious what's the datasize of your input, that is how many rows do you have in A?

Comment: This is essentially a slimmed down version of dynamic programming.  Nice!

Comment: @rayryeng Not sure about dynamic programming, but well my usual vectorized approaches won't be efficient here, so had to go with iterative one! :)

Comment: @Divakar - Yeah I couldn't escape using a `for` loop here either so I feel you.  This pair of solutions is nice because to solve the TSP, you can either brute force it (mine), or use some form of dynamic programming (your's).  I'm actually surprised my answer got accepted TBH.

Comment: @rayryeng haha well you did explain it in a detailed manner! But yeah that  `perms` thing .. I don't know too much of computational stuff there :)

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can see you do this is by brute force.  Also bear in mind that because this is brute force, this will scale very badly as the total number of points increases.  This is fine for just 4 points, but if you want to scale this up, the total number of permutations for `N` points would be `N!` so be mindful of this before using this approach.  If the number of points increases, then you may get to a point where you run out of memory.  For example, for 10 points, `10! = 3628800`, so this probably won't bode well with memory if you try and go beyond 10 points.

What I can suggest is to generate all possible permutations of visiting the 4 points, then for each pair of points (pt. 1 -> pt. 2, pt. 2 -> pt. 3, pt. 3 -> pt. 4), determine and accumulate the distances, then find the minimum distance accumulated.  Whichever distance is the minimum will give you the sequence of nodes you need to visit.

Start with [`perms`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/perms.html) to generate all possible ways to visit four points exactly once, then for each pair of points, figure out the distances between the pairs and accumulate the distances.  Keep considering pairs of points along each unique permutation until we reach the end.  Once we're done, find the smallest distance that was generated, and return the sequence of points to generate this sequence.

Something like:

```
%// Your code
A = [ 1 4 3;
    1 2 3;
    1 6 3;
    1 5 3];
D = pdist(A);
Z = squareform(D);

%// Generate all possible permutations to visit for our points
V = perms(1:size(A,1));

%// Used to accumulate our distances per point pair
dists = zeros(size(V,1), 1);

%// For each point pair
for idx = 1 : size(V,2)-1
    %// Get the point pair in the sequence
    p1 = V(:,idx);
    p2 = V(:,idx+1);

    %// Figure out the distance between the two points and add them up
    dists = dists + Z(sub2ind(size(Z), p1, p2));
end

%// Find which sequence gave the minimum distance travelled
[~,min_idx] = min(dists);

%// Find the sequence of points to generate the minimum
seq = V(min_idx,:);

%// Give the actual points themselves
out = A(seq,:);
```

`seq` and `out` give the actual sequence of points we need to visit, followed by the actual points themselves.  Note that we find one such possible combination.  There may be a chance that there is more than one possible way to get the minimum distance travelled.  This code just returns one possible combination.  As such, what I get with the above is:

```
>> seq

seq =

     3     4     1     2

>> out

out =

     1     6     3
     1     5     3
     1     4     3
     1     2     3
```

What the above is saying is that we need to start at point 3, then move to point 4, point 1, then end at point 2.  Also, the sequence of pairs of points we need to visit is points 3 and 4, then points 4 and 1 and finally points 1 and 2.  The distances are:

- Pt. 3 - Pt. 4 - 1
- Pt. 4 - Pt. 1 - 1
- Pt. 1 - Pt. 2 - 2
- Total distance = 4

If you take a look at this particular problem, the minimum possible distance would be 4 but there is certainly more than one way to get the distance 4.  This code just gives you one such possible traversal.

Comment: @ElayneEngTengSin - It is my pleasure :) This was an interesting problem.  Good luck!

Comment: @rayryeng This is essentially the travelling salesman problem, right? So brute force is quite justified here